# Searching for strings inside files with PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a function to search for all translations in my view files in Laravel and it looks like this:

```
<?php

Route::get('/recursive', function (){
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(base_path('resources/views/')));

    foreach($files as $file){

        $searchfor = 'trans';

        // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');

        // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
        $contents = file_get_contents($file);
        // escape special characters in the query
        $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
        // finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
        $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
        // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
        if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
            echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

and this function gets all the translations which is OK. But it gets the whole line where that translation is:

```
{!! Form::label('body', trans('articles.body')) !!}
{!! Form::label('published_at', trans('articles.published_at')) !!}
{!! Form::label('tags', trans('articles.tags')) !!}
```

And what I need from that result above is only this part:

```
'articles.body'
'articles.published_at'
'articles.tags'
```

What do I need to change in my code to get only this portion above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
/trans\((.+?)\)/m
```

**Details**

```
trans    # the word "trans", literally
\(       # open parentheses, literally
(.+?)    # anything, ungreedily, in a capturing group
\)       # close parentheses
```

And get the second element in `$matches`, not the first, in order to get what's in the capturing group (what you're looking for) rather than the whole match:

```
<?php
$contents = "{!! Form::label('body', trans('articles.body')) !!}
garbage line
{!! Form::label('published_at', trans('articles.published_at')) !!}
gibberish
{!! Form::label('tags', trans('articles.tags')) !!}
blah blah
hello";
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/trans\((.+?)\)/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)) {
    echo implode("\n", $matches[1]); // $matches[1], not $matches[0]
}
```

**Result**

> 'articles.body'
>   'articles.published_at'
>   'articles.tags'

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Oua5B)

Answer (score 0):

Tools like localization-helpers (https://github.com/potsky/laravel-localization-helpers) can do this easy for you - just install this library using composer.

Comment: I would like to make my own, but as you brought this up I want to know did you ever use that what you posted?

Comment: Does it scan for all trans() and then creates a blade view where i can simply write my own translations through browser and save them?

Comment: Yes it scans for all "trans('*')" usage and generates a langauge file - this should be .php-files returning an array like configuration-files do.

Comment: Cool....it's a nice package but I still want to make my own...so this is actually not an answer to my question. This question is more for someone who worked with vanilla PHP